# JavaScript Function, Click Button and Resizing (Reverses Button Function)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My code has a button that changes some CSS via adding and removing classes. I have the JS working fine to do this. The first click adds the class, clicking again removes it and so on around it goes, nothing unusual there.

However, I've also incorporated a function that removes the classes if the browser window is resized at all. My issue is, if I then go back to press the button again after resizing the window, it thinks it should be doing the second click (almost reversing the function) and removes the classes (even though they've already been removed by the resizing), whereas I need the button function to almost reset and have it think the button hasn't been clicked yet after the resizing, so the process can be started from the beginning.

I really hope this makes sense, because its been driving me around the bend, and nothing I've tried will make it work how I would like it to.

Thank you for any help!

Heres the code:

JS/jQuery

```
{
  /* Button Function to add and remove classes. */

  $("#nav-icon").click(function () {
    var clicks = $(this).data("clicks");
    if (!clicks) {
      $(".logo-container").addClass("border-change-image");
      $(".container-fluid").addClass("border-change-header");
    } else {
      $(".logo-container").removeClass("border-change-image");
      $(".container-fluid").removeClass("border-change-header");
    }
    $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
  });


  /* Window Resizing Function */

  $(window).on("resize", function () {
    var size = $(this).on("resize");
    if (size) {
      $(".logo-container").removeClass("border-change-image");
      $(".container-fluid").removeClass("border-change-header");
    } else {
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: _“and have it think the button hasn't been clicked yet”_ - it appears your script “thinks” that, based on what data is stored under `clicks` on the button element. So _set_ that to the appropriate value then, inside your resize event callback …?

Comment: Thank you! Your comment got me out of the tunnel vision, and I've sorted it by pretty much removing the variable storing the data. It all works great now, thank you again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Removed the variable storing the data and just "asked" if one of the div's had one of the classes then add or remove, based on that. Works like a charm.

JS

```
$("#nav-icon").click(function () {
    if ($(".logo-container").hasClass("border-change-image")) {
      $(".logo-container").removeClass("border-change-image");
      $(".container-fluid").removeClass("border-change-header");
    } else {
      $(".logo-container").addClass("border-change-image");
      $(".container-fluid").addClass("border-change-header");
    }
  });
```

Comment: In that case, you should be able to just use [`toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) directly though, without any further check, and without any if/else to begin with.